# Automorphisms of affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$: degree of the polynomials defining the inverse morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In the context of algebraic geometry over an algebraically closed field:

Let $f:\mathbb{A}^n\to\mathbb{A}^n$ be a bijective regular map such that $g=f^{-1}$ is regular.
Write $f=(f_1,\dotsc,f_n)$ and $g=(g_1,\dotsc,g_n)$, where $f_1,\dotsc,f_n,g_1,\dotsc,g_n$ are polynomials in $n$ variables.

Let $d_f$ be the maximum among the degrees of $f_1,\dotsc,f_n$.
Let $d_g$ be the maximum among the degrees of $g_1,\dotsc,g_n$.

Can we bound $d_g$ in terms of $d_f$ and $n$?

Comment: this might be worth asking on mathoverflow